# c# combobox problems in setting the list of items

Tags: c#, combobox

I have 2 combobox here. cb1 and cb2.
I need to set like, when cb1.SelectedText = "aa", the list of items in cb2 will be "1,2,3"
when cb1.SelectedText = "bb", the list of items in cb2 will be "5,6,7";
how can i do that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You create an event listener for `cb1` which calls some module that contains the business logic for determining the values to display in `cb2`, then bind `cb2` to those values. (You also come up with better variable names.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wire up the `SelectedIndexChanged` Event for cb1 -

```
cb1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cb1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Handle Event & populate cb2 based on the selected text in cb1 as follows -

```
void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get Selected Text of cb1
        string selectedText = cb1.SelectedText;

        // Populate cb2 based on the selectedText 
    }
```

Hope it helps...